# Passing callback function as parameter

Tags: javascript

I am calling a function like below. Here I am also passing callback function that should be called only after a particular form submit not before that.

```
<div onClick="myNamespace.openDialog(par1,par2,myNamespace.callback(myNamespace.cb,'p1','p2'))">OPEN DIALOG</div>

var myNamespace = myNamespace || {};
myNamespace={
     return{
        cb:function(p1,p2){alert(p1+"  cb  "+p2);},
        callback:function(f){f(arguments[1],arguments[2]);},
        openDialog:function(p1,p2,f){
          // aboutBizzNs.cb should be called here only after form submit

        }
     }
}();
```

The problem is `alert(p1+"  cb  "+p2);` is called just after `OPEN DIALOG` is clicked. It should not be like that. It should be called only when I want. What is the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `aboutBizzNs.callback` *immediately invokes* the function supplied as an argument.

---

Compare with the following which creates and returns a [closure (function)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures) which will invoke the function supplied when it iself is invoked:

```
callback: function(f){
    // The f variable is bound in a closure below, which is returned immediately.
    // However, the f function is NOT invoked yet.
    // We also copy the arguments of this function invocation and expose
    // them via a variable which is also bound in the following closure.
    var boundArgs = Array.prototype.slice(arguments, 0);
    return function () {
        // Now f is invoked when this inner function is evaluated, which
        // should be in response to the event.
        return f(boundArgs[1], boundArgs[2]);}
    }
}
```

I'd also use [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply), as in the following such than an arbitrary number of "bound" parameters can be used ..

```
return function () {
    return f.apply(this, boundArgs.slice(1));
}
```

.. *but* this is a fairly common operation and is already supported by [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) (which is part of ES5 and shim-able in other browsers). As such, the original ..

```
myNamespace.callback(myNamespace.cb,'p1','p2')
```

.. could be written as ..

```
myNamespace.cb.bind(this,'p1','p2')
```

.. for the same effect here. A difference is the `this` inside the callback (`cb`) function may differ as `bind` doesn't allow a "pass through" of `this`.

Or, just forget about all these special functions and simply wrap the callback as such ..

```
function () { myNamespace.cb('p1','p2') }
```

Comment: after going through your arguments and details I found that passing `function () { myNamespace.cb('p1','p2') }` as an argument to `openDialog(.....,f)` and then calling `f()` inside `openDialog()` was sufficient for me .Thank you

Comment: @Manish You're welcome! Closures (and functions as first-class values) are a bit tricky to master, but once you master them you're the master of JavaScript ;-)